# CNN model is not considering all the data in the training dataset,but only part of data and i am getting exact same accuraccy in all the epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

## **MY CODE**

```
input_shape=(50,50,1)

model = Sequential()
# Conv2D : Two dimenstional convulational model.
# 32 : Input for next layer
# (3,3) convulonational windows size
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten()) # Output convert into one dimension layer and will go to Dense layer
model.add(Dense(124))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(124))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x.shape
```

(25000, 50, 50, 1)

```
train_lables.shape
```

(25000,)

```
model.fit(x,train_lables,epochs=10)
```

Epoch 1/10
782/782 [==============================] - 57s 73ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 2/10
782/782 [==============================] - 60s 76ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 3/10
782/782 [==============================] - 59s 75ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 4/10
782/782 [==============================] - 55s 71ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 5/10
782/782 [==============================] - 57s 73ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 6/10
782/782 [==============================] - 56s 71ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 7/10
782/782 [==============================] - 56s 71ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 8/10
782/782 [==============================] - 56s 71ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 9/10
782/782 [==============================] - 57s 73ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 10/10

782/782 [==============================] - 59s 75ms/step - loss: 7.6246 - accuracy: 0.5000

**MY INPUT DATA HAS 25000 SAMPLES**

Comment: If you're referring to 782/782 not being all sample, it is. It is displaying number of batches instead of number of samples. Since the default batch size is 32 and you have 25000 individual samples, number of batches works out to be about 782. Why the model is not learning I'm not sure.

Comment: You model does not learn because you use softmax with one neuron, this produces a constant 1.0 output, for binary classification with one neuron you have to use sigmoid activation

Comment: Thank you Can you say where did i specify my batch size as 32 and how can i change it as my model is learning now but i want to change that batch size